# Getting a specific row from PHP database to add to a new empty database upon clicking an "add to playlist button"

Tags: php, html

I have a group project for my web programming class, we are creating a simple music website and have created a database using phpmyadmin for each genre, we have a add to playlist button that should add the selected song to the empty database but we can not figure out why it is not working.

```
<div id="navbar">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font size="6"><a href="home_page.php"><b>Home</a></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="6"><a href="pop_page.php"><b>Pop</a></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="6"><a href="Rap_Page.php"><b>Hip-Hop</a></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="6"><a href="rock_.php"><b>Rock</a></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="6"><a href="country_page.php"><b>Country</a></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="6"><a href="alternative_page.php"><b>Alternative</a></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="6"><a href="playlist_page.php"><b>My Playlist</a></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- End of navbar div -->

<br>

<!-- PHP code here to display the appropriate databse table (genre/playlist) -->
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Music Website") or die("Bad Connect:" . mysqli_connect_error());
$sql = "SELECT * FROM AltMusic";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die("Bad Query: $sql");

echo "<table id = 'database'>";
echo "<tr id = 'tableHead'>
                <td class = 'titleCells'>Title</td>
                <td class = 'titleCells'>Artist</td>
                <td class = 'titleCells'>Album</td>
                <td class = 'titleCells'>YouTube</td>
                <td class = 'titleCells'>Genre</td>
                <td class = 'titleCells'>Add to Playlist</td>
            </tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
                    <td class = 'cells'>{$row['Title']}</td>
                    <td class = 'cells'>{$row['Artist']}</td>
                    <td class = 'cells'>{$row['Album']}</td>
                    <td class = 'cells'><a href='" . $row['YouTube'] . "'target = _blank>" .
        $row['YouTube'] . "</a></td> 
                    <td class = 'cells'>{$row['Genre']}</td>
                    <td id = 'add' class = 'cells'>" ?>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value="+"/>
    </form><?
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Playlist(`ID`, `Title`, `Artist`, `Album`, `YouTube`, 
        `Genre`)
                                SELECT `ID`, `Title`, `Artist`, `Album`, `YouTube`, `Genre`FROM Pop 
        WHERE ";
    }
    echo "</td>
                </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> Title: " . $row['Title'] . " Artist: " . $row["Artist"] . " Album: " .
            $row["Album"] . "YouTube: " . $row["YouTube"] . "Genre: " . $row["Genre"] . "Add to Playlist: " .
            $row["Add to Playlist"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$dbc->close();
?>

<!-- Bookmark to allow uesrs to return to the top of the page once at the bottom -->
<a href=#top>
    <font size="6">Back to top</font>
</a>
```

I have tried to use isset($_POST("") to add it but it can only figure out how to fetch the entire array instead on one single selection.

Please consider that I, as well as all of the members in my groups are fairly new to web programming. If I have not posted correctly or not given specific enough ideas about what I am trying to do please let me know in a considerate way. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you trying to do an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Technically yes, but we need it where when you click the add playlist button, it will add that specific row from the existing database to a new database to be display under their my playlist tab.

Comment: The position of your code in the file does not matter. There will be a new page load when you click the button.

Comment: Can I update an empty database? I thought update was to update a database that had existing data in it. We are starting with an empty database and adding the data to it from the others.